# `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'` on Windows CMD

Tags: python-3.x, windows, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda

I'm trying to execute this code on Windows CMD

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

and I'm getting the following error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

I've tried installing scikit-learn and I get the message

> Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.23.2)

Comment: step 1 is to make sure the program you are installing it with is the same as the python you are executing.  try adding `--version` to both and ensure they match. If not then figure out which you want to use and how to ensure both are using that version.

Comment: Is your virtualenv activated?

Answer (score 0):

Windows CMD ist not good enough. What you need is the Anaconda prompt to run Python properly. If you don't find it in your start menu, simply enter

```
C:\> conda activate
(Anaconda3) C:\> python
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>>
```

in the CMD shell. The altered prompt tells you that Anaconda is activated. The problem is that you probably added the python.exe folder to your system path, which is a bad idea with Anaconda.

And the next time please copy the full dialog into your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not installed sklearn package first install sklearn
which can be done using

```
pip install sklearn
or 
pip3 install sklearn
```